# How to move a room on the list (WWDC 2019 video 204)?

Tags: swiftui

So I'm following along making the SwiftUI list of rooms and I'm stuck on how to fix the move function.

I've looked through the list of methods but I can't seem to determine which one it would be as it seems that the move method no longer exists.

```
func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int)
{
    store.rooms.move(fromOffSets: source, toOffset: destination)
}
```

Value of type '[Room]' has no member 'move'; did you mean 'remove'?

I don't mean to remove but simply to be able to move the room on the list.

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this as well. My best guess is that for the presentation they are using an api surface area that isn't part of the preview yet.  I've found several things that were presented that are not available. Form View is another one for instance.